# Tensorflow c++ windows bazel build giving error while reading extensions file

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-c++

hey guys im trying to install tensorflow 
c++ on windows 10 but im running into this 
issue when i try to do the bazel command

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a basic sanity check to resolve your problem, you need to make sure you are running a specific version of TensorFlow using *the recommended* bazel build tool as specified in the instructions:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

For example, TensorFlow v0.9 should go with Bazel tool v0.11.0. Could you provide this information for you case ?